# How to check if a day has passed in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, date, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have saved this timestamp in a Firestore document:

```
last_check_mmr: 14 dicembre 2021 15:39:01 UTC+1
```

How can I check if a day has passed from that date using Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried to substract 24h from the current date and time and check if the result is greater than or equal to what you have in the document?

Comment: Allennick could you please confirm if this comment helped you? and if it is, @Alex Mamo could you add it as an answer to help the community? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a Cloud Function it is quite easy by using [`Dayjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs), the "minimalist JavaScript library that parses, validates, manipulates, and displays dates".

Something like the following, using the [`diff()`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference#docsNav) method, should do the trick:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const dayjs = require('dayjs');

// Let's imagine you use a scheduled Cloud Funciton
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('...').onRun(async (context) => {

  // Get the value of the timestamp, e.g. by fetching a Firestore document
  
  const docRef = ...;
  const snap = await docRef.get();

  const last_check_mmr = snap.get('last_check_mmr');
  
  const date = dayjs(last_check_mmr.toDate());
  const now = dayjs();

  console.log(date.diff(now, 'd'));

  // If you get a value of 0, it means it is less than a day, if you get -1 or less it is more than a day

  if (date.diff(now, 'd') < 0) {
     // more than a day
  }

  return null;

});
```

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec, How to specify the timezone while getting the current date and time using the dayjs library in firebase cloud functions?